# showing $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or not as a group under addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to see whether $\mathbb{Q}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ or not as a group under addition.

$(\mathbb{Q}, +) \cong (\mathbb{R},+)$?

I know they are not isomorphic as a ring. 
The prove is basically done as follows
First assume there exist isomorphism $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, then from homomorphism property $f(1)=1$, and $f(2)=2=f(\sqrt{2}\times \sqrt{2}) = f(\sqrt{2}) f(\sqrt{2})$, this states that $f(\sqrt{2}) = \pm \sqrt{2}$ but this does not belong to $\mathbb{Q}$, so it contradicts.

But how about group under addition, i tried to do the same thing but here $\phi(0)=0$ is all i have.

Comment: They are not even bijective!

Comment: Yes, i know they have different cardinality, i mean $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable but $\mathbb{R}$ is not. But what i want to do here is construct isomomorphism map and give rise to some contradiction.

Comment: Two groups are isomorphic if there is a group morphism between them that's also a bijection. The latter is impossible here. You won't find any other immediate contradictions as $\mathbb{Q}$ is a nice subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Show that each injective mapping $f:{\mathbb Q}\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ cannot be surjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apart from the question of cardinality, I'd like to point out this property of $(\mathbf{Q},+)$ that is not shared with $(\mathbf{R},+)$.

Given any $x, y \in \mathbf{Q}$, there exist integers $m$ and $n$, not both zero, such that $mx + ny = 0$. (Multiplication by an integer is definable solely in terms of addition.)

This is not true in $\mathbf{R}$. For example, take $x = 1$ and $y = \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

Can there be a bijection between the sets $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb R$? (No)